# How to convert text of choice fields into icons?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

Salve, folks!  I have a choice field in my sharepoint page with choices like this:

```
(1) Go
(2) Warning
(3) Stop
```

Now, I want that to appear in the list as an icon instead of text.  I have a working jquery script for that, but it takes to long to search through all the list for the contained text, and it would be better to use xsl anyway because it renders before it is displayed.

So how can I accomplish this in xsl?  Here is as far as I have gotten, as I am only learning xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" 
  version="1.0" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" 
  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" 
  xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 
  xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" 
  xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">

    <!-- Convert the Scope Field into an icon -->
    <xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Scope']">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Scope='(1) Go'">
                <td class="statusRating1"></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Scope='(2) Warning'">
                <td class="statusRating2"></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@Scope='(3) Stop'">
                <td class="statusRating3"></td>
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Scope" />
            </xsl:otherwise>                
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> 

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the css I want to apply:

```
.statusRating1{background-image: url("/_layouts/custom/images/go.png"); }
.statusRating2{background-image: url("/_layouts/custom/images/warning.png"); }
.statusRating3{background-image: url("/_layouts/custom/images/stop.png"); }
```

Now, I've tried this with and without `mode="Choice_body"` or `mode="MultiChoice_body` and even `Text_body`, and have also tried adding  `<xsl:apply-templates />`
but it never even seems to hook.  The column is definitely named "Scope". Maybe I just have to [add the right mode](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54081/what-is-the-xslt-mode-binding-for-a-choice-field)?

In firebug, I can see that the class is never added.

**[update]** I have noticed that in other places where I have used the template in this fashion, that the template never "took" unless it had the correct `mode` defined.  However, I've googled the world over and can't find the right `mode` to use for a choice field.  I even created a question for *that*, [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54081/what-is-the-xslt-mode-binding-for-a-choice-field).  Also, the use of `thisNode` is from [Microsoft's examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx?ppud=4), where you can modify field types very easily (except in the case of this here choice field).

Comment: BGM, The fact that you have written a template isn't enough for this template ever to be executed. And if it is selected for execution by the code of the XSLT built-in (default)  templates, these templates don't know about any parameter named `$thisNode`, and don't pass such parameter to your template. This means that the value of the parameter when the template is initiated is the empty string -- therefore none of the `xsl:when` test conditions is satisfied and thus the `xsl:otherwise` is chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to define [Custom Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx) for a [SPFieldChoice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.aspx) field in template for `mode` attribute should be used value **body**

Template for modes with names `Choice_body` `MultiChoice_body` are not defined.

So, in your case *template* would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='Scope']" mode="body">
```

---

Template mode attributes defined for rendering SharePoint fields are not documented, but you could find this information in `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL\fldtypes.xsl`. See implementation of template *PrintField* for details.

Hope this helps,

Vadim

Comment: Ah, you caught both my posts!  Thanks!  (other, more detailed post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54081/what-is-the-xslt-mode-binding-for-a-choice-field/54672#54672)

Answer (score 0):

**The fact that you have written a template isn't enough for this template ever to be executed**.

And if it is selected for execution by the code of the XSLT built-in (default) templates, these templates don't know about any parameter named `$thisNode`, and don't pass such parameter to your template.

This means that the value of the`$thisNode` parameter when the template is initiated is the empty string -- therefore none of the `xsl:when` test conditions is satisfied and thus the `xsl:otherwise` is chosen.

**Solution**:

**Either**:

1. Have an explicit `xsl:apply-templates` in your code, that selects the nodes to be matched by the tempate, or:
2. Delete the `<xsl:param>` and replace in the code every occurence of `$thisNode` with `.`.

Comment: But I have three very similar templates that work just fine to convert a text field into a hyperlink.  The only difference is the `choose`.  I suppose I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: I have an xsl file called `fldtypes_custom.xsl` in `_layouts/XSL`, which is automatically loaded by Sharepoint.

Comment: @BGM, Unless you provide a complete source XML document and a complete XSLT transformation, people are limited only to make guesses what might be wrong -- it is in the XML document and XSLT code that you haven't shown to us. Also, XSLT experts are not likely to know how Sharepoint works, and similarly, SharePoint experts most likely don't have too deep understanding of XSLT. If you want to have a proof that the template is ever executed, make it output something distinct -- such as "XXXXXXXXX". Then if you see this string in the output, that means the template was executed.

Comment: I don't have a source XML document (or don't know how to get it) - I am just adding an entry in my custom XSLT file to modify a sharepoint list.  I did tag this question with `sharepoint` AND `xslt` - I don't know what other information to provide, Dimitre.  I'll post the rest of the xslt file for you, however, but I don't think it will help anything.

Comment: @BGM, You can output the source XML document using: `<xsl:copy-of select="/"/>. When you do this, please, copy the result and paste it into your question.

Comment: Dimitre, I'm sorry, where would I put *that*? - I see now that the xml is defined in the aspx file inside an `<XmlDefinition>` tag.  I'll post that for you.

Comment: @BGM -- Just put it in any of your templates that is really executed. you can mark it visusally by preceding and following it with the strings: `"=======================&#xA;"`

Comment: That didn't do anything (I'm sorry for being so difficult!).  Won't my xml (added to my answer) help?  Here is the xpath for `Scope` gotten from SPD: `/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Scope`

Comment: @BGM, No, this looks like a kind of a schema -- not the actual XML document. Did you try to output "XXXXXXXXX" and see whether this is present in the output or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21183/discussion-between-bgm-and-dimitre-novatchev)