# Is there a better way to find and replace a class based on its contained text?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

In my sharepoint page, I need have a multiple-choice field.  I want to replace that text with an icon.

Now, I came up with this jquery function which does, indeed, work.  Problem is that it runs after the page is loaded and makes the page irresponsive until it finishes.

As you can see, it loops through every element with a class of `.ms-vb2` and checks to see if it text matches one of the strings, and then removes the string, but supplies a class.  I will fill up that class's css with a background-image icon.

Is there a better way to do this?  I don't have my heart sold on jQuery, if there is a better way.  Otherwise, perhaps there is a better way to write this function?

```
function setRatingsStyles(){
    var ClassName = ".ms-vb2";
    //var ClassName = ".RatingsCSStoken";
    var ratingscale1 = [];
    ratingscale1[1] = "(1) Go";
    ratingscale1[2] = "(2) Warning";
    ratingscale1[3] = "(3) Stop";

    $(ClassName).each(function (){
         for(i=0;i < ratingscale1.length; i++){
            //$(ClassName).text(ratingscale1[i]).addClass("statusRating" + i).text("");     //we are replacing the text with an icon
            $((ClassName) + ":contains('" + ratingscale1[i] + "')").addClass("statusRating" + i).text("");      //we are replacing the text with an icon
         }
    });

}
```

Here is a truncated snippet I pulled out of Firebug (I removed everything above and below the form tags, as well as the script tags; the `...` are just properties not needed for the example):

```
<div>
<div>
<div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle" style="height: 44px;">
<div id="s4-workspace" class="s4-nosetwidth" style="height: 737px;">
<div id="s4-bodyContainer" style="width:2010px!important">
<div id="ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv">
<div id="powerstrip" class="s4-notdlg">
<div id="toplinkbar" class="s4-notdlg">
<div class="s4-notdlg">
<div id="s4-leftpanel" class="s4-notdlg">
<div id="pagebody" class="s4-ca">
<div id="pagebodytitle" class="s4-notdlg">
<div id="pageholder">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" class="s4-wpcell-plain" ...">
<table class="s4-wpTopTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div id="WebPartWPQ2" class="noindex" style="" allowexport="false" allowdelete="false" width="100%" ...>
<span></span>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ...>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<iframe id="FilterIframe20" ...>
<table id="{...}" class="ms-listviewtable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" ...>
<tbody>
<tr class="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr" valign="top">
<tr class="ms-itmhover" iid="20,4,0" setedgeborder="true">
<td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell">
<td class="ms-vb2"></td>
<td class="ms-vb2">
<td class="ms-vb2">Georgetown IL</td>
<td class="ms-vb-title" height="100%" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this)">
<td class="ms-vb2">Renovation</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">Active</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">Bob Newhart</td>
<td class="ms-vb-user"></td>
<td class="ms-vb2">
<td class="ms-vb2 rating4">(4) High</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">
**...repeated over and over....**
<td class="ms-vb2">(1) Go</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">(2) Warning</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">(3) Stop</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">(1) Go</td>
<td class="ms-vb2">Office</td>
<td class="ms-vb-user">
<td class="ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell">
</tr>
<tr class="ms-alternating ms-itmhover" iid="20,6,0" setedgeborder="true">
<tr class="ms-itmhover" iid="20,8,0" setedgeborder="true">
**...repeated over and over....**
</tbody>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="ms-bottompaging" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ...">
<table id="Hero-WPQ2" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ...>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="masterfooter" class="s4-notdlg" style="clear: both;">
<div id="DeveloperDashboard" class="ms-developerdashboard"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I *can*, but it is a sharepoint page, all rendered in server code and script.  I'll post a snippet for you that I pulled out of Firebug.

Comment: are you able to dynamically modify markup in your server code? Can use `data-` attributes to really improve over using `:contains` which requires a lot of regex parsing

Comment: Yes and No.  It is sharepoint, which is all generated.  If I wanted the mods to work for ALL lists, I'd have to create a web-part or custom solution, which I'm not yet up to doing.  However, I could modify the style output using xsl, but I'm hung up with that here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887872/how-to-convert-text-of-choice-fields-into-icons

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you are looping through these class items a minimum of 4 times (once in your outer loop and three times in your inner loop).  You should switch your loop to something more like the following:

```
$(ClassName).each(function (){
  var $this = $(this);
  var i = $.inArray($this.text(), ratingscale1);
  if(i >= 0) {
    $this.addClass("statusRating" + i).text("");
  }
});
```

I'm not sure if this is ideal as it still has the negative that you are looping through a bit too much. It is better than what you had though. Ideally you would be controlling the HTML that is generated and put the class names in there.

Comment: I agree about the ideal; problem is that I'd have to do it for every page that has the ratings scale.  It would be better to have it done in xslt, but I haven't figured that out yet.  However, your code is a good deal faster than mine. You certainly get my thanks and my +1.  I will wait a little and see if anyone tops that.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions that would improve performance significantly:

Have server code add `data-` attributes to `.ms-vb2` class that contain the values in the text. This will help avoid using `:contains` selector which requires regex parsing of text. Only add the `data-` attribute with server code if there is a value for the element to avoid looping through empty elements.

```
<td class="ms-vb2" data-rating="(1) Go">(1) Go</td>
```

Cache the whole class in variable to avoid searching DOM more than once:

```
var $ratings=$('td .ms-vb2[data-rating]');
```

Loop over `ratingscale1` array and use `filter()` method to create collection of appropriate elements from previously cached object:

```
 for(i=0; i= ratingscale1.length;i++){
     $ratings.filter(function(){
           return $(this).data('rating') == ratingscale1[i];
     }).addClass("statusRating" + i).text("");
 }
```

After thinking about all this while writing this code...you could add the class and remove the text on server which would be faster than in DOM also and classes would exist when CSS is rendered on page load.

Comment: I don't think I can make the server add to the markup because it is made by sharepoint - I'd have to have some custom solution (which I'm not yet up to doing).  Now, I didn't know you could cache the class.  Can I do the caching on Hexxagonal's code?

Comment: whenever a search is likely to happen more than once can always cache selectors. Without being able to modify markup could change my code from `$(this).data('rating')==` to `$.trim($(this).text())==`